# Fit Button size as text length in Android

Tags: android, button, text, togglebutton

i have this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL7Ca.png)

And i wanna to achieve this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBP9.png)

As you see in first picture, the size of togglebutton are same, but i want to set the size of togglebutton as a text dynamically. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
a{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;">Btn 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;">Button 2</a>
<a href="javascript:;">Bt 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;">Long Button Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a text view with a background drawable like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/brand_blue"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

So according to the text view padding, this will get automatically aligned. If you want to display multiple in a row, use recycler view or list view.